# summarizing column values by groups created based on conditionals

Tags: r, date, reshape, dplyr

I have the below dataset:

```
Adv_Code    Change_Dt   Change_Month    April_OPN   May_OPN June_OPN    July_OPN    August_OPN  September_OPN   October_OPN November_OPN    December_OPN    January_OPN February_OPN    March_OPN
A201        12/04/2018  April           0           0       1           0           0           0               0           0                   0           0               0               0
A198        27/07/2018  August          2           0       0           1           2           0               5           0                   0           0               0               0
S1212       10/11/2018  November        0           3       4           0           0           3               0           1                   0           0               0               0
```

I need to divide the monthly transactions into N and V based on the change_month and change_dt.
When the date falls after 15th of the month,the change_month falls on the next month, else the same month as change_dt.
For example, for A198,Change_Month is Aug, hence April_OPN to July_OPN to be grouped under N category and remaining in V category.
For S1212 , since the date falls before the 15th, April - Oct OPN's fall under N and remaining under V.

Expected output:

```
Adv_Code    Change_Dt   Change_Month    N_OPN   V_OPN
A201        12/04/2018  April           0       1   
A198        27/07/2018  August          3       7
S1212       10/11/2018  November        10      1
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Below is the code to reproduce the dataset:

```
Adv_Code <- c('A201','A198','S1212')
Change_Dt <- c(as.Date('12/04/2018'),as.Date('27/07/2018'),as.Date('10/11/2018'))
April_NOP <- c(0,2,0)
May_NOP <- c(0,0,3)
June_NOP <- c(0,0,4)
July_NOP <- c(0,1,0)
August_NOP <- c(0,2,0)
September_NOP <- c(0,0,3)
October_NOP <- c(0,5,0)
November_NOP <- c(0,0,1)
December_NOP    <- c(0,0,0)
January_NOP <- c(0,0,0)
February_NOP <- c(0,0,0)
March_NOP <- c(0,0,0)

df <- data.frame(Adv_Code,Change_Dt,April_NOP,May_NOP,June_NOP,July_NOP,August_NOP,September_NOP,October_NOP,November_NOP,December_NOP,January_NOP,February_NOP,March_NOP)
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: I am not sure where to start even!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` (row-wise). Store the column number where `Change_Month` occurs for that row (`inds`). Take substring of `Change_Dt` and check if the value is greater than or equal to 15 and based on that `sum` the values into two parts and add as new columns.

```
col <- 4 #Column number from where the months start

df[c("N_OPN", "V_OPN")] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
       inds <- grep(x[["Change_Month"]], names(x))
       if (as.numeric(substr(x["Change_Dt"], 1, 2)) > 15)
          c(sum(as.numeric(x[col:pmax(col, inds - 1)])), 
            sum(as.numeric(x[inds:ncol(df)])))
        else
          c(sum(as.numeric(x[col:inds])), 
            sum(as.numeric(x[pmin(ncol(df), inds + 1):ncol(df)])))
}))


df[c(1:3, 16, 17)]
#  Adv_Code  Change_Dt Change_Month N_OPN V_OPN
#1     A201 12/04/2018        April     0     1
#2     A198 27/07/2018       August     3     7
#3    S1212 10/11/2018     November    11     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Adv_Code = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = 
c("A198", 
"A201", "S1212"), class = "factor"), Change_Dt = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("10/11/2018", "12/04/2018", "27/07/2018"), class = 
"factor"), 
Change_Month = structure(1:3, .Label = c("April", "August", 
"November"), class = "factor"), April_OPN = c(0L, 2L, 0L), 
May_OPN = c(0L, 0L, 3L), June_OPN = c(1L, 0L, 4L), July_OPN = c(0L, 
1L, 0L), August_OPN = c(0L, 2L, 0L), September_OPN = c(0L, 
0L, 3L), October_OPN = c(0L, 5L, 0L), November_OPN = c(0L, 
0L, 1L), December_OPN = c(0L, 0L, 0L), January_OPN = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), February_OPN = c(0L, 0L, 0L), March_OPN = c(0L, 
0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: hello Ronak, The logic does not seem to work with the below combination
Change_Month
April 7/4/2017
April 7/4/2017
May 16/04/2017
January 4/1/2018